# Recover from GitHub Desktop

Tags: git, github

I don't use GitHub very frequently and hence I do not have clarity over technical wordings of GitHub.

A few times I have saved my thesis including Matlab codes using Git Shell, last was around three months back. Because of some reason I would like to have all the files which were saved at some specific point of time, I am interested in retrieving all the files as a bundle or zip.

Is it possible? (I hope it should be). If yes please let me know how.

I have GitHub Desktop installed in my computer.
[image]

Thanks

Comment: If you view the commit history in GitHub *web* you can select an individual commit, click "Browse Files" from the diff view and then choose "Download ZIP" from "Clone or download" e.g. https://github.com/taspeotis/DeltaCompressionDotNet/tree/ae5f5316629508a6c8a0a4c5731ac411b5afd70d will download my code as of 4 Jan 2015.

Comment: it's not on web

Comment: Sorry for the red herring, hope you find Git enjoyable. Sounds like Lasse's solution of `git archive` is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [git archive](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) command.

You can use it like this:

```
git archive --format=zip --output=path\to\your\archive.zip REVSPEC
```

`REVSPEC` is either the tag, branch name, or commit hash of the "point in time" you want to build the archive from.

Since I don't use GitHub Desktop I don't know if this particular command is available in the GUI but if it is it is probably named "archive" or something similar as well.

Comment: I too don't use desktop, that's for better viewing, I am learning Git.

Comment: it worked for me `git archive --format=zip --output='D:\ArchiveFolder\archi1.zip' 2efrf...0f2`, where `2efrf...0f2` is SHA